# Recommended hardware configuration for tfs+sharepoint+project server

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, server-configuration, project-server

For a 30 person team, what is the recommended hardware configuration for installing latest version of mentioned products? Please also determine recommended server topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the TFS admin guide:

> **Fewer than 250 users**
>    Single-server (Team Foundation Server and the Database Engine on the same server).
>    1 single core processor at 2.13 GHz
>    2 GB
>    1 disk at 7.2k rpm (125 GB)
>
> **250 to 500 users**
>    Single-server.
>    1 dual core processor at 2.13 GHz
>    4 GB
>    1 disk at 10k rpm (300 GB)

We have a team of 50 members and have a sytem scaled to the 250 user scenario, with a mirrored C (system) drive and a RAID 5 D (data) drive.

Comment: you can find the admin guide at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8175. It has the answers for your questions

Comment: While this might be sufficient for TFS, you won't have fun with SharePoint with less than 8 GB RAM.